# how to print python script output to CMD?

Tags: javascript, python, command-line, printing

I'm a beginner I'm python so please LMK where is my misunderstanding please.

I have a python script called new_1.py, which contains only:

```
def test() :
    print ("BLAendBLA") 

test()
```

I opened CMD at the file location and run `py new_1.py` while expecting to get on CMD screen "BLAendBLA".
i'm using python3 and i'm not sure what am i missing...

any help?
thanks!

Comment: try  `<location of your python executeable>  new1.py" - not sure what `py` you are calling

Comment: same - nothing...

Comment: Running "python3 new1.py" in my machine works correctly.

Comment: tried also python3 new_1.py. same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Python.

First of all, you misused the tag `javascript`.

And secondly, you script looks fine, did you get any error message after you typed the command `py new_1.py`?

Comment: nothing... just make "Enter" and the cmd is ready for the next command...

Comment: can you show the output after typing `py --version` and let me know your platform version? I am suspecting that your python installation may be incorrect.

Comment: output is "Python 3.9.0", i'm on windows 10

Comment: are you in the directory with the correct new_1.py when you run it? Maybe a duped file name. Really, it should work as written.

Comment: yes i'm at the correct directory. I don't know what is wrong. damn

Comment: well i want on the right place.... sorry for inconvenience and thanks 1!!!